# For loop, getting sum of numbers

Tags: loops, sum

I made a for loop that generates a list of numbers from 300 down to 200 in multiples of 11 or 13. My question is, how can i get the sum of those numbers?

```
package Week3.Yedkois;

public class Project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        for (int i = 300; i > 200; i-= 1){ // countdown from 300 to 200

            boolean num = (i % 11 == 0 || i % 13 == 0) && !(i % 11 == 0 && i % 13 == 0); // multiples of 11 and 13 but not booth.

            if (num == true)

            System.out.printf("%-5s", i );

        }   
   }



    }
```

Comment: This looks like a school assignment.

Comment: Hint: you are putting each number into a local variable, put the sum into a global variable.

Comment: One last question, so their are 15 multiples in (i) variable. How do i print 1 variable on 3 lines? So i want there to be 5 multiples per line. The only way i can think of would be to use the index and make substrings for each set of characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        int sum = 0; // variable to store sum

        for (int i = 300; i > 200; i--){ // countdown from 300 to 200

            boolean num = (i % 11 == 0 || i % 13 == 0) && !(i % 11 == 0 && i % 13 == 0); // multiples of 11 and 13 but not booth.

            if (num == true) {

               System.out.printf("%-5s", i );
               sum += i; // Calculate sum for every matched number
            }
        }   
        System.out.printf("Sum = %-5s", sum);
   }
```